# What algorithm does youtube use to generate a transcript for videos?

Tags: youtube, software-design, transcription

I am looking into developing an application to transcribe an audio file for me, then it gives me a document with words or phrases and times spoken, just like YouTube does. I could just upload files to YouTube and then get the transcript but I want to use it offline. Anyone to help? Where can I start?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Youtube, but I would start with [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-emea-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-gcp-1002258&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_171796594481-ADGP_BKWS%20%7C%20EXA%20~%201%3A1_EMEA_EN_ML_Speech%20API_speech%20recognition%20google-KWID_43700017207320664-kwd-58920926700-userloc_20079&utm_term=KW_speech%20recognition%20google-ST_speech%20recognition%20google&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIua6C8NG61QIVDjPTCh3rJwAjEAAYASAAEgI98_D_BwE&dclid=CIftmvLRutUCFVmZdwodudwEhg), and if you're not happy with it, then I'd go through [these 5](https://www.programmableweb.com/search/speech%20recognition) as well.

Also, bear in mind that Chrome has [Web Speech API](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html) built in (and most likely Firefox has something similar, but I never had a need to explore that), so if what you're doing is for web, you should check that out too.

Let us know if this helped.